# Developing another blog application for learning purpose

Tags: blogs

I am thinking of developing a blog application. I understand that this has already been done many times. But i like do for learning purpose.

I like to know for this kind of blog application.

What are the desired features to develop?

Comment: Just take a look at what blogging tools like Wordpress, Typepad, Blogger, MovableType do...

Some of em are opensource, so you can even download their source code and learn something there to...

Comment: The blogging engine is the new "Hello World": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471940/why-does-every-man-and-his-dog-want-to-code-a-blogging-engine/471944#471944

Answer (score 1):

Some interesting features that you may want to implement are (in no particular order):

- WYSIWYG editor (use one of the available like [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)) for writing the posts. This is interesting for the sanitisation of input (you may/may not want your posters to be able to use certain HTML tags for instance).
- upload system for images/files that you want to include in posts
- support of comments with possibility of moderation
- voting system for the posts
- "share me" system (note in Google Reader, share on FaceBook, StumbleUpon etc etc.) (but note [this](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/websites_stop) :D :D)
- support of tags
- automatic suggestion of tags depending on the post text/title
- support for multiple users with different privileges. For instance you may have various types of users (admins, posters, guests) with different privileges: admins can modify all the posts, posters only their own posts, guest can only read. Other things may include different maximum upload size for the images etc etc
- implementation of [linkbacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkback) ([trackbacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trackback) / [pingbacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pingback) / [refbacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refback))

I guess this is already plenty of work! Enjoy!!!

Answer (score 0):

First, see the blog-in-15-minutes [screencast](http://media.rubyonrails.org/video/rails_blog_2.mov) in Ruby on Rails. This shows you the basic components and features and how to implement them, even if you do not want to use Rails.